# How to debug java webapp in eclipse specific to a URL request?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, servlets

In my java application, I have hundreds of images and js files. I want to debug my app (using Springframework ) specific to a image url request, running in tomcat 7. How to do that in Eclipse IDE?

Should I have to include code to compare the urls and set break point

```
{ using javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest getRequestURL()}
```

in the code?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps:

1. In the tomcat bin  folder add a `debug.bat` (for windows) or `debug.sh` (for OS X, Linux, etc.) with the following content (note that `catalina.sh` needs to be replaced with `catalina.bat` for windows):

   ```
   set JPDA_ADDRESS=8001
   set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
   catalina.sh jpda start
   ```
2. Start tomcat using this `debug` file instead of `start` file packaged with default installation
3. From *eclipse*, go to *Debug > Debug Configuration*
4. Select *Remote Java Application* from the left side menu and click on the *New*
5. Add parameters at the left side panel like this:
   [image]
6. Click *Apply* and then *Debug* button. This will attach eclipse debug to previously started tomcat process.